# author posts in views

Tags: views, users, theming

I have a content type and sort theme in a page with views as a table
And now, I want when users go to this page, they can see just the posts that the made them.
see just post made by their-self.
what filter should I do?
How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Add an contextual filter of type `Content: Author uid`
2. Under *WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT IN THE URL* select *Provide default value*.
3. Select *User ID from logged in user*.

Comment: Oh,it's really worked!Thank you a lot.Is there any good video about working with views and the contextual filter and etc on the Internet?

Comment: There is a very good video series for learning views at http://nodeone.se/en/taming-the-beast-learn-views-with-nodeone

Comment: Now how we do say that she just see the people that have the same value in field for example
in the A field that we created in account in configure page?

Comment: I am not sure what are trying to say. I would suggest you to open a new question with this query and mention in details what is it that you want to achieve. Also, the question seems to be out of the scope of current question.